# I am trying to convert at http links to hyperlinks on body load

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to scan my page on document load and convert all links as hyperlinks. This is saying 'x' is null. Can you suggest me how to do this in jquery. I am not sure if .replaceWith works

```
var x = document.getElementById('body');
x.innerHTML = x.innerHTML.replace(/(http:\/\/[^ ]+)/g,'<a href="$1">$1</a>/');
```

Comment: What happens if there already a link somewhere in the body of the document. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: yeah thats completely messing up the page. So there is a plugin like linkify that you can use to check for links precisely and convert it.

Comment: @macho: What, the two solutions I gave below aren't enough?

Comment: @patrick yeah they are enough, and working...thanq.I just forgot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have access to the body via:

```
var x = document.body;
```

No need for a method.

Though there are better ways to create links than to destroy and recreate the entire DOM. Also, this will affect elements that currently have an `href` attribute starting with `http`.

---

**EDIT:** *This is a less destructive way to accomplish what you want:*

```
var re = /(http:\/\/[^ ]+)/g;

function createLinks( els ) {
    $(els).contents().each( function() {
        if( this.nodeType === 1 && this.nodeName !== 'script' ) {
            createLinks( this );
        } else if( this.nodeType === 3 && this.data.match( re ) ) {
            var markup = this.data.replace( re, '<a href="$1">$1</a>' );
            $( this ).replaceWith( markup );
        }
    });
}

createLinks( document.body );
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/dVsqe/

---

Or no jQuery:

```
var re = /(http:\/\/[^ ]+)/g;
var temp = document.createElement('div');

function createLinks( els ) {
    var nodes = els.childNodes, node;
    for( var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++ ) {
        node = nodes[ i ];
        if( node.nodeType === 1 && node.nodeName !== 'script' ) {
            createLinks( node );
        } else if( node.nodeType === 3 && node.data.match( re ) ) {
            temp.innerHTML = node.data.replace( re, '<a href="$1">$1</a>' );
            while( temp.firstChild ) {
                node.parentNode.insertBefore( temp.firstChild, node );
            }
            node.parentNode.removeChild( node );
        }
    };
}

createLinks( document.body );
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/dVsqe/2/

Comment: Hi patrick, the node type is not working when native JS library is downloaded and used. When I use google APi's, then it is working. Any inputs please...

Comment: @macho: Are you saying that it works when you load jQuery from google, but not when you download jQuery and use your local copy?

Comment: yeah....I am loading jquery 1.3 from google and it works fine. But, using jquery 1.4.1 from my local copy doesn;t show any result.

Comment: can u have a look at this http://forum.jquery.com/topic/bug-1-3-b1-selector-nodetype-3-not-working

Comment: @macho: There were breaking changes between jQuery 1.3 and 1.4. You'll either need to update your code for 1.4 or download 1.3 and use that.

Comment: I have two applications where one is based on 1.3 and the other 1.4. I am not sure why the code snippet you gave doesn't work on 1.4. Can you suggest any changes in your code to make it work on 1.4. Thank You.

Comment: @macho: If you're talking about the first snipped, it does work with `1.4`. If you click the example and look at the menu on the left, it's running `jQuery 1.4.4`. I'd assume that there's some other code you're running that doesn't translate from 1.3 to 1.4.

Comment: ...if you're trying to use `[nodeType = 3]`, then that isn't part of my code, and it isn't a valid way to select text nodes (as of 1.4 anyway).

Answer (score 3):

`body` is not the 'id' of the body element; it's the tag-name or, in JavaScript, the `tagName`. Therefore you should use the appropriate JavaScript method `getElementsByTagName()`. As this returns (potentially) a number of elements, you have to specify which of the returned elements you want to work with, in this case the first (and only, I'd imagine), which in JavaScript is the zero-th, so instead you should use:

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
```

References:

- [`.getElementsByTagName()` at Mozilla Developer Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName).

Comment: still the innerHTML doesn't work. I am trying to achieve the same functionality as JS of replacing using JQuery.Thanks

Answer (score 3):

in jQuery

```
$('body').html( $('body').html().replace(/(http:\/\/[^ ]+)/g,'<a href="$1">$1</a>/'));
```

Comment: Yeah, but ideally when I use this line inside document.ready(Function(){});, then all links in my document body should appear as hyperlinks....but, they dont..can you help me

Comment: link me to your  html, so i can reproduce it on my computer

Comment: Hi Johnny your solurion is good if the page didnt have any anchor tags. If there are anchors it adds an extra anchor. But, thank you for the response.

Comment: if u add a space before http in the regex then it should fix that problem. i have edited the code to reflect that..  but that will assume all urls have s space before them, but i dont see why it would be any other way?

Comment: Hi johnny the regex doesn't work at all. I am sorry. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: i removed the edit for the space, when i have time ill playwith it. im at work now